# Subbing Duplicate username with a number at the end

Tags: command-line, bash

Hello currently working on a school project for my unix class.

Creating a user menu to add/create username using the first name + last name to create username(first initial+first four of last)

**Ex. John Smith = JSMIT**

now I can add usernames, but if someone was to enter the same or similar user name, I need to be able to substitute it with a number at the end.

**Ex. James Smith = JSMIT1**

so far this is what I have, I know I need to use the ***substr function in awk***, but im not sure how exactly.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

```
     looptest=y
while [ "$looptest" = y ]
do
        echo -n "Enter Name: "; read name
        echo -n "Enter Last Name "; read last
        echo -n "Continue(y)es or (n)o "; read looptest
        user="${name:0:1}""${last:0:4}"
        echo "$name:$last:$user" >> userData
        done
```

Comment: Does the assignment *require* you to use the awk `substr` function? must you deal with duplicates within the shell loop - or are you allowed to "fix" the `userData` file after?

Answer (score 5):

#### One possible approach with grep

From your code,  I see that you're appending to `userData` file, which means filenames would  increase in their numerical suffix.  So to get next available suffix, we could look through the `userData` file with `grep` and merely count number of lines where username occurs:

```
$ grep -c 'jsmit' users.txt                                                   
2
```

Of course, if returned number is 0, we can just ignore that because it's a new username. Here's a just small script of how that'd work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter first name: " firstname
read -p "Enter lastname: " lastname
username=$(printf "%s%s" "${firstname:0:1}"  "${lastname:0:4}")

num=$( grep -c "$username"  userData )
if [ "$num" -gt 0 ]; then
    username="$username$num"
fi
echo "$username"
```

Test with `jsmit` and `jsmit1` already in the file:

```
$ ./indexed_usernames.sh                                                      
Enter first name: john
Enter lastname: smith 
jsmit2
```

However , note that this is a very naive and simplistic way, and assumes no usernames are deleted or missing indexes and are added in linear fashion.

#### Other things to consider

- As I understand  you're building a small user database in shell script. Consider such case: what if we had `jsmit`,`jsmit1`, and `jsmit2`, but then we removed `jsmit1`. That means the script has to consider which numerical indexes *are actually available*, otherwise if we blindly increment numbers, that can result in a collision.
- Consider capitals vs lowercase usernames. If I enter `John Smith` and `john smith` should that result in a collision ? Should you convert all usernames to lowercase first and then handle collisions ?